# Chart.js Example Isn't working

Tags: chart.js

I pretty much copy pasted from: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ aaaaand my html page isnt doing anything...

heres what is have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js">
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: /* default options from chart.js site */
});
myChart();
```

What am i missing...

I have a src in script, I'm not getting any errors in console..I have the canvas.. I've called myChart()... Idk..

Comment: what function is `myChart();` did you write that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **super** old version of Chart.js. If you update to a more recent version it will begin working.

I also saw the same thing you explained when I used the old version 0.2.0 and it starts working when using the below 2.7.2 version CDN

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js`

You can find the above url from the [Chart.js installation page](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#cdnjs)